# How to use Existing Sequential Visual Studio 2010 workflow code for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

We are using SharePoint Server 2010, so we have developed sequential Visual Studio 2010 workflow as a farm solution using C# code.

Now we would like to use the same code base for share point `online/office` 365 (small business) as a sandbox solution.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I have to ruin your day. VS workflows are deployed as a DLL files ie. Workflows cannot be deployed as a sandboxed solutions. You can: a) Create sandboxed custom action or b) use sharepoint designer to create reusable workflow and import it to visual studio (which hopefully allows sandboxed solution). So basically Office 365 does not support complex workflows.